# Can't build SFML 2.4.1 with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, cmake, mingw

I am trying to build SFML 2.4.1 with CMake GUI for MinGW on Windows 10. I get an error saying that "libintl-8.dll" is missing and a bunch of other errors.

I checked the PATH, "C:\MinGW\bin" and "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" are both there. I found a library called "msys-intl-8.dll" in "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin", tried to rename it to "libintl-8.dll". The "missing" error disappeared but the rest of the errors persist.

**Message in CMake GUI:**

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_73327/fast"
    Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
    CMake Error at C:/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
      The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
      program.

      It fails with the following output:
       Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
      Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_73327/fast"

      Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was:
      "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_73327/fast

      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:40 (project)
```

**Contents of "CMakeOutput.log":**

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.14393 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"
```

**Contents of "CMakeError.log":**

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_2426e/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_2426e/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_acc1b/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_acc1b/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_9db84/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_9db84/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_4e89a/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_4e89a/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_570e4/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_570e4/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_ef272/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_ef272/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_6bcbb/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_6bcbb/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/SFML/SFML-2.4.1-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_73327/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_73327/fast"
```

Answer (score 0):

I manaded to fix the problem, I had to choose Msys MinGW in Generator options instead of just MinGW :)